# Shutting down TaskScheduler does not stop running @Scheduled method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have a class with a method annotated @Scheduled

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyScheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${polling-job-cron}") //each minute
    public void pollingJob() {
        log.info("starting polling job...");
        //some work
        log.info("polling job finished.");
    }
}
```

and a configuration for taskScheduler:

```
 @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("mynameofscheduler");
        scheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        scheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(30);
        scheduler.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());
        return scheduler;
    }
```

I'm trying to use graceful shutdown by using class which waits for `ContextClosedEvent` :

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class GracefulShutdown implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {
    private final ApplicationContext context;
    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    public GracefulShutdown(ApplicationContext context,
                            ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler) {
        this.context = context;
        this.taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
        log.info("Graceful shutdown - start");
        log.info("Closing task scheduler");
        taskScheduler.shutdown(); //1
        taskScheduler.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor().shutdown(); //2
        log.error("Closed task scheduler");
        //give k8s a chance to hit in readinessProbe and stop sending requests to this pod
        try {
            Thread.sleep(80000); //3
        } catch (InterruptedException error) {
            log.info("error while trying to sleep");
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("Closing spring context with startup date, {}, parent: {}, id: {}, name: {}",
            context.getStartupDate(), context.getParent(), context.getId(), context.getDisplayName());
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
        log.info("Graceful shutdown - end");
    }
```

and even though I'm closing taskScheduler and underlying taskExecutor new tasks are still ran by @Scheduled. Code of `GracefulShutdown` is ran when SIGTERM is send, and other that closing taskScheduler it works fine.

```
Graceful shutdown - start
Closing task scheduler
Closed task scheduler
starting polling job...
polling job finished
starting polling job...
polling job finished.
```

threadPoolPrefix is logged in front of those lines (I've cut that above as line were too long to read):

```
{"timeMillis":1534234560001,"thread":"mynameofscheduler","level":"INFO","loggerName":"myclassr","message":"starting polling job..."
```

I thought that maybe some other taskScheduler is used and I'm shutting down wrong one, but its all `mynameofscheduler` which is configured in `@Bean`

Comment: Spring already calls the `shutdown` method, so no need to do it again. Your code will also result in an error as the context is already closed and you are calling close again. AFAIK that will throw an already closed exception (or something alike). So I would actually state that your attempt to graceful shutdown is actually preventing a graceful shutdown.

Comment: unfortunately I haven't started with closing taskScheduler without reason. I've noticed that it still runs @Scheduled method while Thread.sleep(80000) ( which is dirty trick for kubernetes ). So no - it does not shut it down at least not in a way I expect it to be done :) + I get no error you have mentioned.

Comment: It does a shutdown because `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` implements `DisposableBean` and the `destroy` method is called when the context is closed/destroyed. So yes it is shutdown but shutting down doesn't prevent it from accepting other tasks (which is what you see in your logging), shutting it down again (and again) will not change this. Also are you sure that this is the `TaskScheduler` that is used by your `@Scheduled`?

Comment: yes its this TaskScheduler as its threadNamePrefix is logged on same line as 'starting polling job..' (I've cut that as line is really long but will edit/add it to question)

Comment: Then it is weird that it doesn't already shutdown (and apparently your "fix" doesn't help either). Are there (for some reason) multiple instances? Could you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce it?

Comment: Just did a small test, it actually works for me. However the `ContextClosedEvent` is fired before the actual beans are stopped, hence if you sleep inside this `ApplicationListener` that actually prevents the `ApplicationContext` from stopping and thus shutting down the `TaskScheduler`. Manually shutting down the `TaskScheduler` does actually stop scheduling events in my little test.

Comment: ok will dig in, actuator /shutdown do similar sleep in org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.ShutdownEndpoint but maybe I has to do it in new thread explicitly

Comment: It isn't similar. As this sleeps before closing the context. You are sleeping while the context is being closed. It looks similar but it isn't. The `sleep` in the `ShutdownEndpoint` doesn't halt the proper closing of the context, because that hasn't started yet. Yours is blocking the further processing of the `doClose` in the `AbstractApplicationContext` preventing the beans to shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Because by default the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor will wait for all delayed scheduled tasks to finish executing, even if scheduled tasks aren't running at that time.

Try this below:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            this.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor().setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
            super.destroy();
        }
    };
    scheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("mynameofscheduler");
    scheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    scheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(30);
    scheduler.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());
    return scheduler;
}
```

Then the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor will only wait for scheduled tasks which are currently running to finish executing.

Answer (score 0):

thx to [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum). I was messing up with spring shutting down flow. I've fixed that by registering shutdown hook:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AgileStreamApplication.class, args);
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new GracefulShutdownHook(context)));
}
```

and now I don't have to shut down taskSchedulers explicitly. It's done by spring.