# Spring Boot scheduled Runnable tasks continue executing even after server is shut down with an actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm currently developing a Spring-based web platform which makes use of several scheduled processes that access a central database. I wanted to introduce actuators for shutdown and restart. However, I am experiencing an issue: even though the shutdown request is accepted with a 200 response, the application context begins shutting down:

```
2022-10-10 17:37:25.235  INFO 9067 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-10-10 17:37:25.240  INFO 9067 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

And after that, I repeatedly get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at usi.si.seart.service.TaskService$TaskServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bf83a1d.getNext(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at usi.si.seart.scheduling.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:547) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:636) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManager(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:585) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:487) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:734) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.createNativeEntityManager(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:485) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:410) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

So in spite of the fact that the server is reported as "shutting down", the scheduled processes still continue executing. My scheduler definition within the configuration class is as follows:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setClock(Clock.systemUTC());
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(3);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("PlatformScheduler");
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

    threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(getRepoMaintainer(), new CronTrigger("0 0 0 * * SUN"));
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(getTaskCleaner(), new CronTrigger("0 */15 * * * *"));
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(getTaskRunner(), 500);

    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Where the `getRepoMaintainer`, `getTaskCleaner` and `getTaskRunner` are all methods that produce custom `Runnable` instances: `RepoMaintainer`, `TaskCleaner` and `TaskRunner` respectively.

Comment: you don't have to specify any `destroyMethod`, `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ` implements `DisposableBean` and has a `destroy` method which is automatically called. Destroy will call `shutdown` so that shouldn't cause the issue.

Comment: @zapl I tried both with and without the `destroyMethod` specified, the problem persists. I will edit the question to remove the annotation parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the fixes suggested by the other users worked. In the end, I managed to solve my problem by virtue of a custom `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` implementation:

```java
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    private final Set<ScheduledFuture<?>> futures = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, long delay) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = super.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, delay);
        futures.add(future);
        return future;
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future =  super.schedule(task, trigger);
        futures.add(future);
        return future;
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        futures.forEach(future -> future.cancel(true));
        super.shutdown();
    }
};
```

This way I ensure that all scheduled tasks are cancelled pre-shutdown no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

As you have specified that your custom destroyMethod is "shutdown" have you defined that method with the required destruction statements?

Something like this,

```
public void shutdown() {
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.shutdown();
}
```

Edit-
Most probably the error here is, even though the shutdown has been initiated the tasks are still running but the container is shutting down. This releases the resources required for the task to execute and the error is thrown.
What you can do here is perform a graceful shutdown where you prevent the shutdown of the container until the tasks have finished executing.

Your issue is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837217/shutting-down-taskscheduler-does-not-stop-running-scheduled-method) and you can try out his [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51871297/20190240).

Or, you can configure a termination period like so, `setAwaitTerminationSeconds(*seconds*)` Check more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-graceful-shutdown). But then you might face this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26719).

Comment: Hi @Jalena. I took a look at the JavaDoc for the `destroyMethod` of `@Bean`, and to my understanding the method name you provide is the name of the method which will be called within that class. In the case of the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` I specified `shutdown`. Since the annotation does this method inference by default, I tried removing the annotation value. Debugging the program I noticed that the `shutdown` method is indeed called, but the same issue remains...

Comment: Hi @OzrenDabić, I have edited my original answer you can try out the solutions. Hope it helps!

Comment: I will take a look at the first solution. Since some of these scheduled tasks typically run for considerable periods of time, they may delay shutdown for a considerable amount. I want the shutdown to be immediate, which is why using `setAwaitTerminationSeconds` is out of the question.

Comment: @OzrenDabić In that case you can find some useful methods in this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html) such as removeOnCancelPolicy or ExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy. This is also addressed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26719)